# Questions edited in such a way that they cannot be recognized

Tags: discussion, vandalism

I specifically refer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3701788), but this is not the first time I observe the following behavior: after a question is answered it is changed by the author in such a way that it cannot be anymore recognized.

Is there any method to prevent this? I would suggest that an edit of a question with an upvoted answer has to be treated similar to deletion: the action should require approval of the community per review.

Comment: Sometimes its deleted once answered. Completely disrespectfull. You can flag and choose option " in need of moderation". It worked many times for me.

Answer (score 23):

This is essentially vandalism of the question and is generally disapproved of here.  I've rolled the question back to the one with at least a clear title and added a comment asking the user not to vandalise.  My suggestion would be to start with that approach: it's least intrusive and respects the norms of the community.  There's an argument to be made about individual freedoms, but to a certain extent some of those are voluntarily given up by attempting to join the community here.  And I'm not writing a political tract so I'll leave it at that.

Of course, some users will continue to vandalise their question and act like spoiled children and then it's necessary to flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 4):

It would be an overreach to prevent all edits, even when a Question has received an upvoted Answer.  However typically I roll back the defacing "edit" the first time it happens (the Edit history lets you see that), and leave an "admonishing" Comment.

If the OP persists in defacing their post (or deleting it), I flag for moderator attention.